# Simple chrome extension timer not starting at '00:00:00' upon launch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a simple hobby project which is a chrome extension that acts as a simple stopwatch/timer. I want the timer to *launch* with the default state as '00:00:00', and also *start* (upon button click) at '00:00:00' (currently working). I'm new Javascript. Here is my script:

```js
let timerIntervalId = null;
let startTime = 0;
let isTimerRunning = false;

function startTimer() {
  if (!isTimerRunning) {
    startTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    timerIntervalId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    isTimerRunning = true;
    document.getElementById('start-stop-button').classList.remove('start');
    document.getElementById('start-stop-button').classList.add('stop');
    document.getElementById('start-stop-button').textContent = 'Stop';
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerIntervalId);
    isTimerRunning = false;
    document.getElementById('start-stop-button').classList.remove('stop');
    document.getElementById('start-stop-button').classList.add('start');
    document.getElementById('start-stop-button').textContent = 'Start';
  }
}

function resetTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerIntervalId);
  startTime = 0;
  isTimerRunning = false;
  updateTimer();
  document.getElementById('start-stop-button').classList.remove('stop');
  document.getElementById('start-stop-button').classList.add('start');
  document.getElementById('start-stop-button').textContent = 'Start';
}

function updateTimer() {
  let currentTime = Date.now() - startTime;
  let hours = Math.floor(currentTime / (60 * 60 * 1000));
  let minutes = Math.floor((currentTime % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000));
  let seconds = Math.floor((currentTime % (60 * 1000)) / 1000);
  let timerDisplay = `${padZero(hours)}:${padZero(minutes)}:${padZero(seconds)}`;
  document.getElementById('timer').textContent = timerDisplay;
}

function padZero(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return `0${num}`;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  updateTimer();

  document.getElementById('start-stop-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    startTimer();
  });

  document.getElementById('reset-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    resetTimer();
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="start-stop-button">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="reset-button">Reset</button>

<div id="timer"></div>
```

I've added these however it doesn't seem to work as expected. Upon launch, it seems to display something like '466052:05:02'

```
let startTime = 0;
```

and in my html.pop

```
<div id="timer" class="timer">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, your question is more likely to be answered if you show a full working example. I've edited to include an assumption of what your HTML looks like - please edit to update it as required.

Answer (score 0):

So the biggest issue with your code is **startTime** variable and its values.
Javascript is returning you a difference in milliseconds when you are substracting dates. So when you are substracting Date.now() and startTime you get the wrong result. What you should do to fix this is assign startTime to Date.now() everywhere where you are assigning it to 0. This way you will always get the correct difference in milliseconds between the two dates.

You can read more about date operations in Javascript here - https://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-date.html